How to capture the email ID of users who created row data in Google Sheets for workspace and non-workspace users?
I am working with Google Sheets and need to capture the email addresses of users who create or modify row data. This is required for both workspace (Google Workspace) and non-workspace users.
i want to Automatically log the email ID of the user who creates a row in a specific column (Col A).
Ensure it works for both Google Workspace users and non-Google Workspace users (i.e., users outside the organization).
I’ve attempted to use an Apps Script with the Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() function, but it only works for authenticated users. For non-workspace users, it either returns blank or the script owner’s email.
Script:
    function ListinglogEdit(e) 
    {
    var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
    var sheetName = sheet.getName();
    // Only run the script on the "Listing" sheet
    if (sheetName !== 'Listing') {
    return;
    }
    var range = e.range;
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    var timestamp = new Date();
    // Define the "Created By" column (Column I)
    var createdByColumn = 9; // Column I (1-based index: 9 = 9th column)
    var row = range.getRow();
    // Column number for Property ID (adjust as needed)
    var propertyIdColumn = 1; // Assuming the Property ID is in column A
    // Only log the creation details if the Property ID is being set for the first time
    var propertyIdCell = sheet.getRange(row, propertyIdColumn);
    var createdByCell = sheet.getRange(row, createdByColumn);
    // If the Property ID is being set and no "Created By" value exists, log the user's email
    if (propertyIdCell.getValue() && !createdByCell.getValue()) {
    createdByCell.setValue(userEmail);
  }
}


Have you considered creating a form instead of sharing a spreadsheet for data input? Form responses automatically appear in a separate tab in the spreadsheet in a row-oriented fashion and are thus easy to process with spreadsheet functions such as query() and filter().
